# Изменение ширины блока в зависимости от того стоит ли рядом с ним блок, либо он уже покрутился наверх, и на его месте пустая область

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

на странице имеются 2 блока (аналогичное левой (узкой) и правой (области контента) "В контакте"). Когда мы прокручиваем страницу вниз, то левая колонка уезжает наверх и на ее месте появляется пустая область, задача состоит в том чтобы правый блок становился во всю ширину, чтобы закрыть эту пустую область. Попытался написать сам но что то делаю не так, подскажите.

```js
var wnd = $(window);

wnd.scroll(function() {
  var top = wnd.scrollTop(),
    leftblock = document.getElementsByClassName('blockk'),
    hi = leftblock.offsetHeight;
  if (top < leftblock.offsetHeight) {
    $('.block').addClass("active");
  } else {
    $('.block').removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.blockk {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  /*9opacity:0;*/
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  background: #333;
  transition: 200ms;
  color: #ccc;
}
body {
  height: 10000px;
}
.block.active {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockk">
  <h3>Это блок, который уедет наверх</h3>Равным образом постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности в значительной степени обуславливает создание дальнейших направлений развития. Равным образом постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности
  требуют определения и уточнения модели развития. Повседневная практика показывает...
</div>
<div class="block">
  <h1>Это блок, который должен стать во всю ширину</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде и css несколько ошибок:

1. [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) возвращает коллекцию элементов, а у коллекции нет свойства `offsetHeight`.
   Для решения нужно взять конкретный элемент, например, `getElementsByClassName[0]`
2. проверяется не верное условие, в данном случае класс актив ставится когда видны оба дива, поэтому нужно просто поменять знак `<` на `>`
3. Недостаточно просто установить ширину в классе active, необходимо также установить смещение слева.

```js
var wnd = $(window);
wnd.scroll(function() {
  var top = wnd.scrollTop(),
    leftblock = document.getElementsByClassName('blockk')[0],
    hi = leftblock.offsetHeight;
  if (top > leftblock.offsetHeight) {
    $('.block').addClass("active");
  } else {
    $('.block').removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.blockk {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  /*9opacity:0;*/
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  background: #333;
  transition: 200ms;
  color: #ccc;
}
body {
  height: 10000px;
}
.block.active {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blockk">
  <h3>Это блок, который уедет наверх</h3>Равным образом постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности в значительной степени обуславливает создание дальнейших направлений развития. Равным образом постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности
  требуют определения и уточнения модели развития. Повседневная практика показывает...
</div>
<div class="block">
  <h1>Это блок, который должен стать во всю ширину</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: в своем решении написал такой вариант, var el = document.getElementById("blockk").offsetHeight а ниже условие, тоже рабочий вариант оказался. Но интересно, что в коде означает [0] ? Сам никак не найду статью где в теории о всех этих выборках почитать можно, поотому все на практике осваиваю, Передумываю проблему и пытаюсь решить

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, все очень просто. это вообще называется [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), в данном случае это означает что берем элемент с индексом `0` в коллекции

Comment: ух.. трудно пока что, никакой логики не увидел кроме того что .blockk это первый элемент в коде соответственно индекс [0] тогда у .block должен быть индекс [1]. а если не так то я вообще закономерности не увидел)

Comment: я думал вот эта строка означает возьми блок такой-то leftblock=document.getElementsByClassName('blockk'), а следующая измерь у него высоту leftblock.offsetHeight;

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, эта строка `document.getElementsByClassName('blockk')` говорит, возьми все элементы у которых указан класс `blockk` в вашей разметке только один такой элемент, к нему мы и обращаемся по индексу 0

Comment: все понял теперь)